# How to perform authentication with React hooks and react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to authenticate user on each route change with `react-router-dom` and `react hooks`. 
The idea is that each time user navigates to a route the system makes an api call and authenticate the user. 
I need to achieve this because I use `react-redux`, and on each window reload the redux state is not persisted. So i need to set the `isLoggedNow` prop to `true` again:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  checkOnEachRoute: checkReq,
  isUserLogged,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const [isLoggedNow, setLogged] = useState(isUserLogged);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const fetchStatus = async () => {
        try {
          await selectisUserLogged();
          setLogged(true);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
      fetchStatus();
    },
    [isUserLogged],
  );
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isLoggedNow ? (
          <div>
            <Component {...props} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

I then would use the above `PrivateRoute` like this:

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch location={props.location}>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/sidebar" component={Sidebar} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

First the `isUserLogged` is `true`, but after window reload I get an error `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.` 
So how can I achieve this, so on each window reload I authenticate the user? I am looking for some kind of `componentWillMount`.

Comment: did you have a chance to resolve this issue?

Comment: @camelCase yes!

Comment: care to share? :) facing exact same issue at the moment

Comment: @camelCase See my answer, does it solve it for you?:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this works (where `isUserLogged` is a prop from redux):

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, isUserLogged, ...rest }) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setAuth] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLogged = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const url = new URL(fetchUrl);
        const fetchedUrl = await fetchApi(url);
        setAuth(fetchedUrl.body.isAllowed);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchLogged();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-nested-ternary
        isUserLogged || isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : isLoading ? (
          <Spin size="large" />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me too, just have a question why do you have isUserLogged passed in props?

Comment: @camelCase I had an idea to wrap `fetchLogged();` in `ìf(!isUserLogged)...`, so fetch only if not isUserLogged :)